# Why does this JDialog not draw properly when called from a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm having a problem with the display of a JDialog when called from a JFrame. The JFrame only contains a button. When pressed, this launches a JDialog with a JLabel, JTextField and JButton.

The JFrame displays fine. The JDialog displays strangely, kinda like it's trying to draw it (or elements of it) offset multiple times! As you move the mouse around over different components, it keeps refreshing, but still weirdly. As soon as you use the mouse to resize the JDialog, it behaves normally (doesn't matter whether you increase/decrease the size).

This is how it first appears:

[image: The dialog showing JButtons drawn weirdly]

After resizing it a little, it is drawn properly:

[image: The dialog drawn properly after resizing]

Where am I going wrong please?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Demo extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Demo());
    }
    
    public void run() {
        setTitle("My JFrame");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Launch JDialog");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Dlg();
            }
        });
        add(btn);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
    

class Dlg extends JDialog {
    public Dlg() {
        setTitle("My JDialog");
        
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnl, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        
        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("Label 1");
        JTextField txt1 = new JTextField(5);
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        
        pnl.add(lbl1);
        pnl.add(txt1);
        pnl.add(btn1);
        
        add(pnl);
        
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### Edit

This is on Windows 10 with JDK 17.0.2

Comment: Works fine for me, maybe you should include your OS and java version? Also, have you considered using 'setContentPane' instead of 'add'?

Comment: Works fine for me.  It almost looks like you're violating the paint chain responsibility some where

Comment: This is on Windows 10 with JDK 17.0.2. I've tried using setContentPane(pnl) instead of add(pnl) - no difference for me. Interesting that it seems to be working for other people though, thanks for trying it! :)

Comment: Works fine on Windows 11 with openjdk 17.0.1

Comment: Works fine for me on Windows 10 with openjdk 17

Comment: Are you running the exact code in your question? Have you got any look and feel set, or other code not included in the question? You could try to specify a minimum size for your JPanel `pnl.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));` which should force the size of your JDialog so that the components fit correctly.

Comment: @sorifiend Yes, that's the exact code I'm running. `pnl.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));` doesn't seem to help, but thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a [similar issue](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=230959) descibed in an Apache NetBeans Bugzilla. [Comment 7](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=230959#c7), by "everflux", describes setting a JVM parameter:

> I assume this is due to Java 8 enbabling the xrender extension by default. I have serious graphics issues with Netbeans 8/Java 8 on Nvidia machine, flickering, windows only scrolling partly etc.
>
> I added the following flag to the netbeans startup options:
> -J-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true
>
> this seemed to mitigate the problems, at least during a 10 minute test period. I encourage other users experiencing graphics problems to test it and report their results.

Adding `-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true` either on the command line or in Eclipse as a VM argument in the Run Configuration has fixed it for me.